# Reproject large raster using Python

Tags: python, coordinate-system, rasterio, rioxarray

I have some large rasters that I want to reproject in a memory-safe way, using a second raster as a template . This code works nicely for smaller ones, but when they are large the Python kernel becomes unresponsive and crashes. I believe it's a memory issue. How can I reproject large rasters, with the result being written to a TIFF file?

```
import rasterio
import rioxarray
import xarray

my_raster = rioxarray.open_rasterio("large.tif")

reference = rioxarray.open_rasterio("template_large_tif")

reprojected = my_raster.rio.reproject_match(reference)

reprojected.rio.to_raster("output.tif")
```

Answer (score 0):

To do out-of-memory reprojection in Python, you have to:

1. Be sure to have Dask in your environment
2. As stated in [rioxarray](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/html/examples/reproject.html), use another reprojection tool. I advise you to use [ODC Geo](https://odc-geo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)'s one.
3. Read your data with chunks `rioxarray.open_rasterio(..., chunks=...)`
4. Use odc reprojection

Small example with a reprojection to change a stack projection:

```py
from dask.distributed import Client, LocalCluster
import rioxarray
from odc.geo import xr  # noqa
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

# Create Dask local cluster
Client(LocalCluster())

# Open the stack
stack = rioxarray.open_rasterio("large_stack.tif", chunks={"band":3, "x":2048, "y": 2048})
print(stack.rio.crs)
# >>> EPSG:32633

# Reproject stack
stack = stack.odc.reproject(
    how="epsg:32632",
    resolution=20,
    resampling=Resampling.nearest,
    dst_nodata=-9999,
    num_threads=16,
).compute()
print(stack.rio.crs)
# >>> EPSG:32632

# Save to disk
stack.rio.to_raster(r"output.tif", dtype="float32")
```

Comment: Thanks for this example remi. I am wanting to 'match' my reprojection to an existing raster/template however - so use the template file for the origin, nodata, resolution, crs etc. Would you be able to guide me on how to edit your code to do that please?

Comment: Here is the documentation: https://odc-geo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_api/odc.geo.xr.xr_reproject.html
You should take the info from the raster you want to reproject to and feed it to this function